Is Python a selectively interpreted language? Why does the following code not work?
As a program runs from top to bottom, why does the following code throw an error directly without executing the first line in the block?
if 5 > 2:
 print("Two is less than Five!")
        print("Five is greater than two!")

Error:
File "/Users/____/Desktop/Python practise/practise.py", line 3
print("Five is greater than two!")
IndentationError: unexpected indent

Definitions vary. Python itself claims it is interpreted but not by my definition.python compiles a source file in to byte code and then executes that byte code. Each source file compilation is autonomous - it doesn't depend on any other .py file. But it does not do line by line compilation / execution like a purely interpreted language would.

To be precise, Python is not an interpreted language. It's a compiled language. It gets compiled into Python byte code, which is an interpreted language. Certain errors like SyntaxError or IndentationError occur at compile time, not at runtime  before the script can even run, which makes sense if you think about it: if you have syntax errors in your source code, it is not valid Python source code, and cannot be compiled.

The entire file is parsed and compiled to byte code before execution and it is a parsing error so no code has executed yet.

Thank you for the answer. It makes sense that the entire code will be compiled before execution, but even in that case, why does Python execute the program if there are errors outside the blocks and only throw an error when it reaches that specific line where the error is present? I am sorry, I am a beginner. So, are there some sets of syntax errors like this one that will prevent the code from running at all? Like, is it strict for errors inside a block?

All syntax errors prevent the code from running.  It has to parse all lines successfully first to generate byte code.  If parsed successfully, the byte code is executed and runtime errors are discovered line-by-line.
